# global min for multivariable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ at $(0,0)$ so $\nabla f(0,0)=(2x,2y)=0 \implies (0,0)$ is a critical point.

As $f(x,y)-f(0,0)=x^2+y^2>0$, then $(0,0)$ is the global minimum.

I have no idea how this last expression holds. How can you know if $x^2+y^2>0$ without knowing the domain of $x$ and $y$? If both variables are zero, then the inequality would not be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2 + y^2$ is always positive for $x, y \ne 0$

Comment: but how do you know that x and y can never be zero?

Comment: Because the square of any non-zero number is positive